# HTTP Status 415 - Even thou application/json is specified

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

Am trying develop backend services with Spring MVC. Here am writing a service which will consume and produce JSON data. I have specified the producing and consuming formats of the service but still am getting the HTTP Status 415.

Model Class Order.java

```
package com.limitless.engage.models;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Ram K Bharathi on 9/2/2016.
*/

public class Order {
private String order_id;
private int user_id;
private int tableNo;
private String status;
private String time;
private String date;
private transient List<OrderItems> orderItems;

public Order(){

}

public Order(String order_id,int user_id, int tableNo, String status, String time, String date, List<OrderItems> orderItems) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.tableNo = tableNo;
    this.status = status;
    this.time = time;
    this.date = date;
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}

public String getOrder_id() {
    return order_id;
}

public void setOrder_id(String order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public int getTableNo() {
    return tableNo;
}

public void setTableNo(int tableNo) {
    this.tableNo = tableNo;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String data) {
    this.date = data;
}

public List<OrderItems> getOrderItems() {
    return orderItems;
}

public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItems> orderItems) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Order{" +
            "order_id=" + order_id +
            ", user_id=" + user_id +
            ", tableNo=" + tableNo +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", time='" + time + '\'' +
            ", date='" + date + '\'' +
            ", orderItems=" + orderItems +
            '}';
}
}
```

Controller Class OrderController.java

```
package com.limitless.engage.controllers;

import com.limitless.engage.models.Order;
import com.limitless.engage.responses.OrderResponse;
import com.limitless.engage.services.OrderServices;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

/**
* Created by Ram K Bharathi on 9/3/2016.
*/
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
public class OrderController {
OrderServices orderServices = new OrderServices();

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> newOrder(@RequestBody Order order)throws Exception{
    orderServices.createOrder(order);
    OrderResponse orderResponse = new OrderResponse();
    orderResponse.setOrderId(order.getOrder_id());
    orderResponse.setMessage("success");
    return new ResponseEntity<OrderResponse>(orderResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

I am using Chrome Postman extension for checking the services. I have setted the content-type headers also in Postman.

JSON Object:

```
{   
"order_id":"231",
"user_id":1,
"tableNo":1,
"status":"placed",
"time":"10:00 PM",
"date":"2016-09-04",
"orderItems":[
    {
        "order_id":"231",
        "item_id":1,
        "quantity":2,
        "taste":"sdbhsfjsdf",
        "comment":"shdbfhgeuywe",
        "totalPrice":20.00
    },
    {
        "order_id":"231",
        "item_id":2,
        "quantity":3,
        "taste":"sdbhsfjsdf",
        "comment":"shdbfhgeuywe",
        "totalPrice":45.00
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share the json object here? and also make sure you are doing "POST" request..

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga I have added the json object. Yes am making POST request only

Comment: are you using jackson mapper for object conversion?

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga No. Would you give some reference what is it and how to use it? It would be helpful.

Comment: I know how to do using spring boot but not exactly in spring. This [link](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services) might help you

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Its no problem you can give me Spring Boot reference also. @RavindraDevadiga

Comment: this is the [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) for spring boot

Comment: Still my problem not solved

Comment: check this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/)